# How does OAuth 2.0 protect against compromised accounts?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am in the process of implimenting OAuth 2.0 for my API and I started wondering about compromised accounts. Lets call my service A and the client service B.

Scenario:

- User's account on A is comprmised
- Attacker authorizes through OAuth 2.0 with B, allowing private information to be viewed via B
- User changes password, to protect account

If something like this occurred, wouldn't the attacker still be able to view the user's private information via B, due to the OAuth access token not expiring upon password reset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too agree with your thinking. The OAuth2 specification doesn't have a countermeasure for this. But the vendors out there provides various countermeasures for this. For example, user dashboards where users can see the applications and devices which are currently holding authorizations. Then users can revoke any suspicious application.

Comment: and the access token retrieved to access B should be short-lived so that the attacker needs to back to A to get a new one, which would not be possible if the password has changed